# Confusion about a implementation of the system function in Unix

Tags: c, unix

A implementation of the Unix `system` function  from *APUE*:

> Figure 8.22 The `system` function, without signal handling

```c
#include    <sys/wait.h>
#include    <errno.h>
#include    <unistd.h>

int
system(const char *cmdstring)   /* version without signal handling */
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int     status;

    if (cmdstring == NULL)
        return(1);      /* always a command processor with UNIX */

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        status = -1;    /* probably out of processes */
    } else if (pid == 0) {              /* child */
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmdstring, (char *)0);
        _exit(127);     /* execl error */
    } else {                            /* parent */
        while (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0) {
            if (errno != EINTR) {
                status = -1; /* error other than EINTR from waitpid() */
                break;
            }
        }

        // if(waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0){
        //     if(errno != EINTR){
        //         status = -1;
        //     }
        // } 
    }

    return(status);
}
```

Why does it use a `while` loop for `waitpid` instead of a `if` statement that I add in the comments? I tried with `if` and did not get anything wrong so far.

Comment: In fact *all* blocking system calls can return `EINTR` that you need to retry.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Hmm, as described in `man waitpid`, if a process were stopped or resumed by a **signal**, this kind of state change will be caught by `waitpid`, but they are considered as a successful return of `waitpid`, these **2 kinds** of **signals** are not the same as the `EINTP` interruption signals as we talk about, am I right?

Comment: Those are signals to the *waited-for process* and here we're talking about the signals received by the process running `waitpid`.

Comment: and again, as explained in the duplicate the `EINT` **`R`** handling here isn't specific to `waitpid` but *any* blocking system call can fail with it and you need to be prepared to retry.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Hmmm, but if `the child was stopped by a signal; or the child was resumed by a signal.`, `waitpid` will return a positive pid value indicating a successful return, is that right?

Comment: No, it will not return at all if the child was merely *stopped* (not terminated) or resumed, because of the flags (the 3rd argument) that are set to 0

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK, I rechecked the man page and you are right. The man page kinda misled me. So anyway.. `EINT` **`R`** does not include interruption caused by stop process signal or resume process signal, I just want to make sure about this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides the child process ending, the `waitpid` function could return early if it was interrupted by a signal.  If that happens to be the case, the `if` block won't be entered and `waitpid` will be attempted again.

Without the loop, if `waitpid` gets interrupted you end up in a state where the parent process doesn't wait for the child and you end up with a zombie process when the child does exit.  That zombie won't be cleaned up until the parent process exits, at which point the init process becomes the parent and automatically waits for the zombies.

Comment: @Rick no, child's termination does not cause an error status. It will be a **successful** call then!

Comment: Hi @dbush, today I learnt that there's *automatic restarting* mechanism for most BSDs and linux, so come back to this question, again, why should I write the loop? 1. By default, `waitpid` restarts automatically. 2. Moreover, there's no user defined signal handler here, so no signal will be caught, thus I think any system calls in the parent process won't be interrupted.

Comment: @Rick Automatic restarting on Linux only happens if the signal handler was set up with the `SA_RESTART` flag, so it is not default behavior.  And this example is probably geared to be used in the general case where no assumptions are made about other signal handlers.

Comment: Yes, I do also think this example is for general use, not particularly based on BSDs and linux (The author sometimes take Solaris as example). And thank you again~

Comment: Wait... Like I said in the first comment, there's no user defined signal handler here, so no signal will be caught,  thus I think any system calls in the parent process won't be interrupted. From this perspective, the "retry" loop is still not necessary/useless, I think?

Comment: @Rick If you know that this piece of code will not be used as part of a larger codebase that has signal handlers, then in that case yes you don't need the loop since a signal will terminate the process.  If this code is part of a library then you have to account for that situation.