# What does "wait and waitpid are always interrupted when a signal is caught" mean?

Tags: c, unix, signals, wait, interrupt

From *APUE*:

> **To prevent applications from having to handle interrupted system
>   calls, 4.2BSD introduced the automatic restarting of certain
>   interrupted system calls.** The system calls that were automatically
>   restarted are `ioctl`, `read`, `readv`, `write`, `writev`, `wait`, and `waitpid`. As
>   we’ve mentioned, the first five of these functions are interrupted by
>   a signal only if they are operating on a slow device; **`wait` and `waitpid`
>   are always interrupted when a signal is caught.** Since this caused a
>   problem for some applications that didn’t want the operation restarted
>   if it was interrupted, 4.3BSD allowed the process to disable this
>   feature on a per-signal basis.

Does it mean that before *automatic restarting* was introduced, if a process catch a signal, `wait` and `waitpid` would immediately stop waiting and execute the subsequent code?

For example:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler(int sig){}
void handler2(int sig){}


int main(){
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
    signal(SIGUSR2, handler2);    

    if((pid == fork()) < 0){
        printf("fork error\n");
    }else{
        if(pid){
            //child
            //do something, needs several hours.
        }else{
            //parent
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            printf("Hello world\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If not providing *automatic restarting*, when I run this program in the background `gcc test.c && ./a.out &`, then I send a signal `kill -SIGUSR1 pid` or `kill -SIGUSR2 pid`, `waitpid` would return and the code after `waitpid(pid, &status, 0);` would execute.

And if providing *automatic restarting*, `waitpid` would execute again and the parent will remain waiting.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: An interrupted system call will return -1 (or whatever it uses to indicate an error) and set `errno` to `EINTR`. Whatever happens next depends on how the caller handles that case. If it's restartable it won't return with that particular errno code, unless otherwise documented to do so. It'll just keep going until it returns for some other reason.

Comment: Note that you should use `sigaction()` rather than `signal()` to gain control over this, and `sigaction()` provides a control flag `SA_RESTART` to specify whether system calls should be resumed after a signal is handled.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler However, `signal()` by default _does_ apply the restart behaviour nowadays on linux and bsd (at least)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original behaviour of `signal()` (System-V semantics) was, to interrupt any system call if the process currently slept, execute the signal handler and the system call returns with `-EINTR`. Then, BSD4.3 invented the *restart* mechanism, which would restart any system call automatically after it was interrupted. This avoids having to write a loop for each syscall if signal handlers are involved.

Linux did not change the semantics of the `signal()` **syscall**. However, the `signal()` **glibc wrapper function** nowadays calls the syscall `sigaction()` with `SA_RESTART` flag by default. So, if you do *not* need the restart behaviour, you have to call `sigaction()` and omit that flag.

So, your code indeed makes use of the *restart* mechanism on both BSD and linux

Comment: Hi @Ctx, I read the book again and a question just came up to my mind. 1. It seems that only those so-called "slow system calls" can be interrupted. 2.And within all the "slow system calls", not all of them can be restarted automatically. Am I right about these two statements?

Comment: If those 2 statements were correct, how can I know which system call is one of the "slow system calls" ? And within those "slow system calls", how do I know which can be restarted automatically? Does the manpage contain this information specifically?

Comment: @Rick Slow syscalls are all syscalls that can sleep for an indefinite time. If there is the `EINTR` documented to the syscalls, it can be interrupted. As far as I know, all slow syscalls can be restarted.

Comment: I am using Linux btw. :)

Comment: Ok I got itttttttttttt. Good. Just check if `EINTR` was documented. I will keep that in mind. Last question please: I don't understand why the retry loop code needed from a previous question I asked [confusion-about-a-implementation-of-the-system-function-in-unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233149/confusion-about-a-implementation-of-the-system-function-in-unix).

See the comments I made just now under the accepted answer.

Comment: Hmm, if trying to sum it up here, the question is: for a system that does not have restart mechanism, the "retry" code is surely needed. But take the example in my previous question, if there's no user defined signal handlers there, then no signals will be caught, thus any system calls won't be interrupted. Am I right about this?

Comment: Ah, that answerer responded to me. Then I won't bother you. Thanks again @Ctx

Answer (score 1):

`wait` and `waitpid` like any other blocking function can be interrupted with `errno` set to `EINTR` - this is *exactly because* a signal handler can do *very little* - mostly set some flags. Now if a blocking function would *not* return with `EINTR`, how could you react to an signal in any way?!

But this also means that you need to have a complicated loop over every function - you might have *some* signals for which you know you don't want the system calls be interrupted, so you can set this signal to have automatic restart.